# Back Button in Master List

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, back-button

I am having a Navigation Drawer Layout in MainActivity.

By clicking on the navigation drawer item, it will redirect to another Activity which is Master/Detail flow.

I want a back button on the Toolbar of this activity to get back to the MainActivity.

I added this code, but only an Icon of back button is displayed.

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: Does it take back to you to the previous activity when you click on that back arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the `onCreate()` method of the Activity with the Back arrow icon in the Toolbar:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Location");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Also, override the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method in the Activity

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourFirstActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        return true;

    }
```

Override the `onBackPressed()` method in the Main Activity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks.. It worked, but when I press the back button from the main activity it jumps to the past activity where i came from Instead of Closing app.

Comment: @mauliksompura check my updated code..Override the onBackPressed() method in the Main Activity..it will work for you